# What to call someone who does not sleep much

Tags: word-request

I don't think it is sleepless because it is much used for sleepless nights not for people, but I found an incident in Coca where it was used to describe a man. Anyway, if you have a sleepless night it means, I think, that you want to sleep but you cannot because you have a medical condition whatever level it is, but not because you have a lot of work you want to finish.

If there isn't any, then I would like to know if there is a word that describe someone who does not sleep a lot at night because that's his nature or they love night life.

> It is an old house, painted white and well kept, standing behind a low
>   stone wall tufted with moss, and it dates back to 1790. There are many
>   rooms for **a sleepless man** to walk through. I knew that if I were a
>   better person, I would have stayed up with him, the way I used to do
>   each year. But I was tired, and longed for sleep the way I used to
>   long for the press of our two bodies. And besides, I didn't want to go
>   through this yet again.
>   *The wife : a novel by Wolitzer, Meg.*

Note: if you think the title of the post is not quite right fix it please.

Comment: A related idiom: **burn the midnight oil**, which NOAD defines as _read, study, or work late into the night_. It describes the action, though, not the person. Borrowing from Damkerng's answer, one could say: _"Don is a real **night owl**; he **burns the midnight oil** almost every night."_

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can use a **night owl**, or a **night-person**.

I think *a sleepless man* is fine. Another similar word is *an insomniac* (a person who suffers from insomnia), but I believe that you know it already.

Actually, what you describe sounds pretty much like me myself. :)

Sometimes, people called me *a vampire*, *a batman*, or *a dark knight*, which is not quite to my taste. In casual chatting, I personally prefer *a night dweller* or *a man of the night* more.

Here is an excerpt from Wikipedia's page [Night owl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_person):

> A **night owl** or **evening person** is a person who tends to stay up until late at night. The opposite of a night owl is an early bird, a lark as opposed to owl, someone who tends to begin sleeping at a time that is considered early and also wakes early.

Comment: I think this is a good question to start doing [a little/adj.] research with Coca esp. to check the connotation of the proposed answers. I know I can use learner's dictionaries, but sometimes they do not give you much. I've just been watching some Youtube videos about Coca.

Comment: @learner I guess you mean COCA (the corpus), maybe?

Comment: COCA is great. It's helped me to sort out some of my English usages, though sometimes I wish that they could provide more powerful searching. :)

Comment: I will +1 this for **night owl**. I'm not quite so fond of the other two suggestions, although if the question was about someone who gets up early, _morning person_ would be my first choice.

Comment: Updated as J.R.'s commented. I think *night dweller* does not fit in general writing.

Comment: You probably mean *dark knight*  although I don't think that term is actually used for a night owl.  I'd reserve that term for a black-clad billionaire vigilante metropolitan protector.

Comment: As an American, I have never heard any other term other than "night owl" used to describe such a person. Other terms, like "night person" or "creature of the night," tend to refer to being active and/or social in the night -- bar hopping, clubbing, events,etc. -- but not necessarily routinely foregoing sleep.

Answer (score 6):

> **Night Owl**

A night owl is specifically someone who stays up late at night.

> **Evening/Night Person**

An evening or night person is more generally someone who does better in the evening or at night, meaning they're more awake or productive at those times.

> **Sleepless Man**

I understand what this phrase means, but it sounds literary to me. I wouldn't use it conversationally.

> **Man of the Night**

There's a term at least in American English, "lady of the night", which is a euphemism for a prostitute. I would stay away from the term "man of the night", since my first reaction would be to interpret it to mean a male prostitute.

Comment: Ah, thank you about *man of the night*. Now I know what they meant (or tried to imply) when they teased me in some chat rooms. :)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Oh no! Well, forewarned is forearmed. :-)

Comment: Oh, my! A *man-of-the-night*, in chat rooms. I've heard about **them** before! ;^)

Comment: @Damkerng: I don't think anyone uses "man of the night" these days (200-300 years ago when it *was* more common, it often meant a *burglar, night-thief*). People still use the far more common ***lady** of the night* (usually facetiously, since it's generally recognised as "dated") to mean a *prostitute*.

Answer (score 3):

You could call that person "a **nocturnal** creature" to suggest that they party often late into the night;  or if you wish to point out that they're not getting enough sleep, they are **sleep-deprived**.

Answer (score 3):

One who suffers from insomnia (difficulty sleeping) would be called an insomniac.

Answer (score -1):

"Creature of the Night" (or Night Creature/Night Person);
"Daysleeper";
"Nochternal"